# Why does my `train_test_split()` returns same samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, train-test-split

Why does my `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()` returns same samples of `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` each time I run the code, even though I have kept `shuffle=True`, and I have not manually defined the seed value?

I am printing the samples like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100, shuffle=True)

print (y_test)
```

Comment: You are forcing a specific random state. Remove it and you will get different results

Comment: Ahh man that was foolish of me, thanks! can you please post your comment and answer, and I can tick it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `train_test_split` `random_state` controls the state of the sample (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

> Controls the shuffling applied to the data before applying the split. Pass an int for reproducible output across multiple function calls

To get different results, simply remove the parameter.